# Is there any way to add absolute path for add_menu_page function?

Tags: admin-menu, add-menu-page

I am creating a plugin for *add menu* option to WordPress admin and using below function for that:

```
<?php add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); ?>
```

But I would like to add absolute path for menu option in the place of `$menu_slug`.

[image]

please see the  screen shot, I have created both " Header and footer " using add_menu_page function. I would like to give absolute path for both header and footer. I know plugins are available for this but I am creating my plugin with different functionality.

Comment: Could you narrow down absolute path to where? If it's another site entirely then WP probably won't let you without much grief. For same site it depends.

Comment: Please read my question once again I have update my question.

Comment: But _where_ does those link point to? A file in your theme? Plugin?

Comment: I would like for plugin

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a clean way to put arbitrary link into the menu item. At most you could change it with JavaScript after the fact.

However there is an edge case that allows you to load plugin file there.

1. Pass as `$menu_slug` argument a path to a plugin file relative to plugins directory, for example `plugin-folder/boo.php`.
2. Omit `$function` argument.
3. This will generate link like `admin.php?page=plugin-folder/boo.php`.
4. Following the link will load the file as content of admin page.

There isn't actually much benefit over just using callback for output. But from technical point of view this is about as close as possible to including a *file* in there.

Comment: but I want to add third party link there.reay my question I want to put absolute path.not like your given example

Comment: Then you are stuck with JS most likely. I don't quite follow why would Header/Footer send user out of admin entirely, but if that's what you need to do — WP doesn't do it.

Comment: You can use this method and just redirect to the external URL. Following the example here, inside the `plugin-folder/boo.php` file include `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/">`.